# NameError: name 'variable' is not defined Python

Tags: python, variables, append

So I am not a pro in python and I am stuck at an error when I am creating a program here is the code

```
# A game that will tell that the news is fake or not.

# Welcome message
print("Want to know that a news is fake or not?\nYou are at a right place. Welcome to FakeNewsDetector.org\nAt here we provide the news which is not fake and you can add more news if you want!!\nSo are you excited? Let's get started\n")

# User input + print for input
print("What thing you want do?")
print("1: Ask a news is fake or not?\n2: Tell a news it is fake or not\n")
number = int(input("We will answer your question just enter the number. Press ctrl+c anywhere if you want to exit: "))

# if then else



# Appending part
if number == 2:
    number = int(input("What is the number of news you are adding?: "))
    whatAreYouTelling = input("What news you want to say? Not include that the news is false or true: ")
    with open('news.txt', 'a') as f:
        a = f.write(f"\n{number}: {whatAreYouTelling}")
    
    trueOrFalse = input("Is the fact true(T) or false(F)?")
    if trueOrFalse == "t" or trueOrFalse == "T":
        fact = True

    elif trueOrFalse == "f" or trueOrFalse == "F":
        fact = False

    else:
        print("Invalid") 



# Reading part
elif number == 1:
    with open('news.txt', 'r') as f:
        a = f.read()
        print(a)

    news = int(input("What news do you want to ask? Enter number: "))

    if news == 1:
        fact = False
        print(f"The news is {fact}.")

    elif news == 2:
        fact = True
        print(f"The news is {fact}")

    elif news > 2:
        print(f"{trueOrFalse}")
else:
    print("Invalid")

# print("\nThanks for using our news service. I hope you like it\n Created by Anant Gupta\n Class 7D\n Homework: ATL")
```

And when I run my code and append a random value an error comes like this

```
[anant@anant-hpprobook440g4 atlProject]$ python -u "/home/anant/Desktop/anant/codingPlayground/pythonProject/atlProject/main.py"
Want to know that a news is fake or not?
You are at a right place. Welcome to FakeNewsDetector.org
At here we provide the news which is not fake and you can add more news if you want!!
So are you excited? Let's get started

What thing you want do?
1: Ask a news is fake or not?
2: Tell a news it is fake or not

We will answer your question just enter the number. Press ctrl+c anywhere if you want to exit: 2
What is the number of news you are adding?: 3
What news you want to say? Not include that the news is false or true: Hello I am nothing
Is the fact true(T) or false(F)?F
[anant@anant-hpprobook440g4 atlProject]$ python -u "/home/anant/Desktop/anant/codingPlayground/pythonProject/atlProject/main.py"
Want to know that a news is fake or not?
You are at a right place. Welcome to FakeNewsDetector.org
At here we provide the news which is not fake and you can add more news if you want!!
So are you excited? Let's get started

What thing you want do?
1: Ask a news is fake or not?
2: Tell a news it is fake or not

We will answer your question just enter the number. Press ctrl+c anywhere if you want to exit: 1
1: Obama tweeted 'ashamed to shake hands with Modi'
2: Kamala Harris hasn't attacked Indian government on farmers
3: Hello I am nothing
What news do you want to ask? Enter number: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anant/Desktop/anant/codingPlayground/pythonProject/atlProject/main.py", line 51, in <module>
    print(f"{trueOrFalse}")
NameError: name 'trueOrFalse' is not defined
[anant@anant-hpprobook440g4 atlProject]$
```

I am not a good programmer but please accept my piece of code. I am working for 1 hour and not able to solve the error. If anyone solves I will be highly thankful. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`TrueOrFalse`'s scope is limited to your first `if` block. To make it accessible within your second block, you need to declare it outside of your `if` statements, for example by setting it to `False` first.

Comment: Thanks, but how I will set its value to true when I have entered True? It can only be accessible for false values only

Comment: @AnantGupta that is a structural problem with your code, not just a syntax error.

Comment: @stenlal So please can you provide the full code? I will be very happy 